# Could not connect MongoDB of Google Cloud from local robomongo

Tags: google-app-engine

I host my project and db in Google cloud platform. Both are running well. The problem is that we need to access the mongo instance outside VM.  We was trying to access the instance externally form my local robomongo 0.8.3 platform using the IP(130.211.50.141) and default port 27017. We are able to ping the ip 130.211.50.141 , but when trying to connect, it is not working. Lastly, Instead of robomongo, I also use console to connect the server using the IP (host) and failed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you tell me which OS you use?

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of ways you can get access to your GCC(Google Cloud Compute) MongoDB from your Robomongo. I'm using SSH to connect to my GCC MongoDB.

1, Make sure you have your ssh key in your mongodb instance located in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. If not, added your key into it.

2, Create a connection: [image: create a connection]

3, Set your SSH connection: [image: set your SSH connection]

Comment: Thanks Yong, for you help. I install robomongo 0.8.4 to get SSH tab in connection. Now I need to find the details for SSH tab. Actually I use to logged in to my G mail account and then open https://console.developers.google.com/project/my-project and go to compute engine and open developer console using SSH button for the instance. I want to find the details for SSH tab like SSH Address, SSH User Name. I think others will be same for me. Can you please help me how could I find these in my GCC.

Comment: @AmitabhaSaha You don't have to open SSH console to find your ssh address. It's the left of your SSH console link in the VM instances list. Which means your GCC's instance external IP address is your SSH address.  SSH user name is your GCC account name with dashes, something like yourname_gmail_com.

Comment: I am getting following error ```Resource temporarily unavailable. Authentication by key (/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa) failed (Error -18). (Error #11)``` And can you please elaborate 1st step. Thankyou.