# Connect Robo3T to compute engine mongodb using authentication

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, robo3t

I am trying to connect my local Robo3T to compute engine. I tried using ssh but i couldnt. Is there way using authentication to connect to mongodb instance running in google cloud compute engine.

Comment: Can you explain how you tried using SSH, as in with a regular SSH client, the Google Cloud SDK or Cloud Console?

Can you paste on the question what the error messages are (using “ssh -vvv” or “gcloud compute ssh --verbosity=debug --log-http -- -vvv” accordingly) along with the commands you have used?

Comment: I also suggest you to take a look on the GCE official [SSH Troubleshoot Guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh).

Comment: @fhenriques I tried using this answer of so https://stackoverflow.com/a/30136166/4700693 . I not very experienced regarding ssh therefor i am looking for authentication. The problem i was getting was ```Failed to create SSH tunnel to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22.

Error:
Resource temporarily unavailable. Authentication by key (/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa) failed (Error -18). (Error #11)``` in robo 3t while making connection following the steps given in link.

Comment: So, if you haven't done it already follow these [instructions](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/authentication/use-public-key-authentication-with-ssh/#manually-copy-an-ssh-key)  to copy the public SSH key of the machine you're trying to connect from into the instance which has mongodb running.

Comment: I followed the steps, i am getting this error [link](https://imgur.com/U6PtlPe)

Comment: First try to connect through the terminal with the SSH utility and the triple verbose flag like “ssh -vvv ...” to see if a plain SSH connection works. Before that, it would be good to confirm that connections on port 22 are allowed from the internet in your GCP project, that is in its VPC Network Firewall rules. If not you could create one with the source IP addresses range (CIDR block) consisting in the of the machine you're trying to connect from. To make your IP address a CIDR block, you just what can suffix it with “/32”.